# how to create a list of combinations from a given list of numbers

Tags: r, combinations

In R, I would like to get a list of all vectors of length from 1 to 3 made out of numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. In total 160 vectors. I have been trying with this:

```
library(iterpc)
I3 = iterpc(5, 3, ordered = TRUE, replace = TRUE)

getall(I3)

I2 = iterpc(5, 2, ordered = TRUE, replace = TRUE)

getall(I2)

I1 = iterpc(5, 1, ordered = TRUE, replace = TRUE)

getall(I1)
```

But I don't know how to make a list of vectors from the results I get.

Comment: Take a look at `?combn`

Comment: If you mean combinations, there are only 25: `do.call(c, lapply(1:3, combn, x = 1:5, simplify = FALSE))`. If you mean permutations, there are 155: `rbind(expand.grid(1:5, 1:5, 1:5), expand.grid(1:5, 1:5, NA), expand.grid(1:5, NA, NA))`

Comment: yes, this is what i needed. Thank you.